# Lock fillable pdf form

Tags: pdf, forms, lock

So i got this pdf file to fill out. I wanna export it to a normal, non-fillable pdf using Acrobat Reader. I cant manage to do it. I tried printing it and select export to pdf in printer setup, however, "printig to pdf is not supported".
What, Adobe wants me to either buy Acrobat Pro version or print out my document and scan it again?

EDIT Btw im on OSX

Comment: According to this (http://www.iskysoft.com/edit-pdf/how-to-print-pdf-on-mac.html), you may not need any special software to print to a pdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Adobe wants me to either buy Acrobat Pro"

Yup -- well Acrobat Standard would work too. ;)

Adobe Reader is for *reading* PDFs, not saving them in a different/modified form.

Easy solution: Get one of the many virtual PDF printer utilities available ([first Google match for 'OSX PDF Printer'](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfwriterformac/)), and then use that virtual printer to "print" from Reader to a (static) PDF file.

Comment: Just a comment: if you go down that route and you happen to be `Chrome` user, then there is no need to search for free PDF printer, `Chrome` has it as a built-in functionality. Just open the PDF with the browser and print it to PDF using CTRL+P, followed by `Save as PDF`

Comment: Thank you so much, you kinda saved me from running to copy shops to print, then sign and scan back in a loaddd of documents :D The Chrome solution also kinda works, the pdf is locked after, however if i open it with Preview, the fillable fields are plain white.